# i want to set my regional setting to english (UK) on load of my program how can i do so?

Tags: c#

i m using c# and i want to set my regional setting to english (united kingdom ) when i load my application how can i do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses localization. Below are some links that speak about localization, the first and second using EN-GB, one for a normal application and one using resource files:

- [Using Custom Cultures—Custom Culture Locale IDs](http://en.csharp-online.net/Using_Custom_Cultures%E2%80%94Custom_Culture_Locale_IDs)
- [.NET - Localization using Resource file](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Localization.aspx)
- [Globalization and localization demystified in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Kb/aspnet/localizationByVivekTakur.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx)

Comment: it's not about localization, but to force the culture

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim newCulture As CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-UK")
CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture
```

I don't now a way to do this in the app.config. But this works.