# Different time formats on different time calls

Tags: asp.net, date, format, datetime-format

I have an ASP.Net application which takes the current time using **"DateTime.UTCNow"**.

While I am accessing the page from the application server itself it shows the time in the format : **M/dd/yyyy (10/22/2013 6:45:18 AM)**

But if I tries to access this page from another machine/client it shows the format as **dd/M/yyyy (22/10/2013 2:44:24 AM)**.

As a result when I parse this time I am getting error - **"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."** in one machine  But it works fine in the other machine(server itself).

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Siva

Comment: Do you mean you get a different result when you call ToString() on the date object? If so, that is because ToString() is using the current culture to generate the string and that might be different between the server and your machine.

Comment: Can you add parsing line in your question?

Comment: But before parsing itself I am getting different formats.. That is while executing DateTime.UTCNow returns two different formats on calling same page from different machines

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. Try setting the regional settings on the client machine to the same as that of the server. It worked for me

EDIT :[i want to set my regional setting to english (UK) on load of my program how can i do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361256/i-want-to-set-my-regional-setting-to-english-uk-on-load-of-my-program-how-can/2362821#2362821)

This should set you on the right path with regional settings

Comment: Is it a good work around as I have to change all my client machine configurations.

Comment: Have you looked at this? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361256/i-want-to-set-my-regional-setting-to-english-uk-on-load-of-my-program-how-can/2362821#2362821

Answer (score 0):

In your code every time you read the time, format in M/dd/yyyy eg:

```
time = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/dd/yyyy"); ///time is the time you read from PC
```

Comment: As per your comment I changed my code like : DateTime curDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime( DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("M/dd/yyyy"));. Now iam getting the exception here

Comment: try DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

Comment: Again the same exception. My exact point is I am getting different time formats on the same machine for different client calls. After taking this time I am parsing this time to string at later part of  the code. I am getting exception at this part of code if the call is from the client machine and it works fine if the call is from the server machine. Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 var time = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
```